# Código fonte em português?

Tags: código-fonte

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de uma ferramenta utilizando Django/Python. Esta ferramenta é direcionada para uma aplicação específica, portanto não será reutilizada. O código fonte também não será publicado.

Entretanto, ao final do trabalho deixarei o sistema em produção na empresas, e desejo outras pessoas (muito provavelmente brasileiras) possam fazer a manutenção ou desenvolver novas funcionalidades.

Minha dúvida é: devo desenvolver o código em inglês ou em português?

Por padrão, e respeitando as boas práticas, sempre faço tudo em inglês, mas nesse caso há um modelo de dados bastante específico, e terei que fazer traduções não triviais do português para o inglês.

Além disso, pelas razões mencionadas acima, não parece haver necessidade real de deixar o código em inglês.

Qual a opinião de vocês? Devo escrever código em português ou inglês?

Comment: Detalhe que a duplicata é uma pergunta fechada.

Comment: OK, de fato é duplicado e a resposta está a contento. Não havia encontrado a outra pergunta pois ela não uso o termo código-fonte. Devo apagar esta pergunta?

Comment: Acredito que não há necessidade de apagar. Só frisei que o sistema deixou marcar como duplicata uma pergunta sujeita a opiniões que estava fechada.